# Seg Fault at function call

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a program that will perform different functions to a tree, and so far all of them work, except for the printing function. It worked previously, but while trying to work out some kinks in the other functions (without messing with it), now that they are fixed this one suddenly doesn't work, and I can't fathom why. Here's my code:

main.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "lcrs.h"

int main()
{
char *temp1;
char *temp2;
temp1 = new char;
temp2 = new char;

lcrs tree;

do{
    cout << "LCRS> ";
    cin >> temp1;
    if(strcmp(temp1, "quit") == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(strcmp(temp1, "insert") == 0)
    {   cin >> temp2;
        bool error;
        for(int i=0; i<strlen(temp2); i++)
        {
            if(!isdigit(temp2[i]))
            {
                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                error = true;
            }
        }
        if(!error)
        {
            tree.insert(atoi(temp2), tree.root);
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(temp1, "height") == 0)
    {
        if(tree.root == NULL)
            cout << "-1" << endl;
        else
            cout << tree.getHeight(tree.root) << endl;
    }
    else if(strcmp(temp1, "preorder") == 0)
    {
        cout << "Root is " << tree.root->data << endl;
        tree.print(tree.root);
        cout << "" << endl;
    }
    else if(strcmp(temp1, "search") == 0)
    {
        cin >> temp2;
                bool error;
                for(int i=0; i<strlen(temp2); i++)
             {
                       if(!isdigit(temp2[i]))
                       {
                                cout << "Error!" << endl;
                               error = true;
                     }
                }
               if(!error)
                   {
                         if(tree.search(atoi(temp2), tree.root))
                cout << "true" << endl;
            else
                cout << "false" << endl;
                }

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error! " << endl;
    }
}while(strcmp(temp1, "quit") !=0);

return 0;
}
```

lcrs.h:

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

class node{
    public:
    int data;
    node *right;
    node *below;

    node()
    {
        right = NULL;
        below = NULL;
    }
};

class lcrs{
    public:
    node *root;
    bool search(int, node*);
    void print(node*);
    void insert(int, node*&);
    int getHeight(node*);

    lcrs()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
};
```

lcrs.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include "lcrs.h"

bool lcrs::search(int x, node *b)
{
    if(b == NULL)
        return false;
    else
    {
        if(b->data == x)
            return true;
        else
        {
            return search(x, b->right) || search(x, b->below);
        }
    }
}

void lcrs::print(node *z)
{
    if(z->below == NULL || z->right != NULL)
    {
        cout << z->data << ",";
        print(z->right);
    }
    else if(z->below != NULL && z->right == NULL)
    {
        cout << z->data << ",";
        print(z->below);
    }
    else if(z->below != NULL && z->right != NULL)
    {
        cout << z->data << ",";
        print(z->below);
        print(z->right);
    }
    else if(z->right == NULL && z->below == NULL)
     {
             cout << z->data << "";
     }


}

void lcrs::insert(int x, node *&a)
{
    if(a == NULL)
    {
        node *newnode;
        newnode = new node;
        newnode->data = x;
        a = newnode;
    }
    else if(a->data < x)
    {
        if(a->right != NULL)
        {
            insert(x, a->right);
        }
        else if(a->below != NULL)
        {
            if(a->below->right != NULL)
            {
                insert(x, a->below->right);
            }
            else
            {
                insert(x, a->below);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            node *n;
            n = new node;
            n->data = x;
            a->below = n;
        }
    }
    else if(a->data > x)
    {
        if(a->below != NULL)
        {
            insert(x, a->below);
        }
        else
        {
            node *n;
            n = new node;
            n->data = x;
            a->right = n;
        }
    }
}
int lcrs::getHeight(node *h)
{
    int height = 0;
    node *n;
    n = new node;
    n = h;
    while(n->below != NULL || n->right != NULL)
    {
        if(n->below != NULL)
        {
            n = n->below;
            height ++;
        }
        else if(n->right != NULL)
        {
            n = n->right;
        }
    }
    return height;
}
```

I get a seg fault right at the **tree.print(tree.root)** function call. I have put a print statement at the very beginning of the function and it never makes it to that, so I am kind of confused as to where the problem is.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ever heard of a fancy thing called debugging?

Comment: You really should try to strip that code down to what's really neccessary to reproduce the error. Easier for you to track down what's wrong on your own, and easier for us to read

Comment: Make a diff with your previous revision and find out what you screwed up when "ironing out" those kinks.

Comment: Most probably you're passing a NULL pointer to the `print()` method somewhere. You should use a debugger to figure out where this happens (as others already recommended).

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issues. It may have something to do with the way you read input, stuffing strings into buffers that hold a single character (*please* use std::string instead - it's there for a reason) or it might have something to do with the fact that tree.root might be null and you're dereferencing it: `cout << "Root is " << tree.root->data << endl;`

Also, you really should try to trim things down when posting code. This serves two purposes: it helps you (because you may actually *discover* what is going wrong on your own, or at least isolate the fault, as you are trimming things down) and it helps us since we don't need to go through pages and pages of code.

Comment: I have checked that the root is not null, using that statement you have right there, and it is not. And I was afraid that if I posted only what is relevant to the problem I might leave something out that an outside eye might catch.

Comment: You are *not* checking if root is null or not null. You are, unconditionally, dereferencing root right there, and it may very well be null.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it was simply a little typo. (Of course it was.) 
Thanks to all of those who gave legitimate answers and sincerely tried to help.
And also, thanks to all of those who gave me sass. I appreciate that AFTER I have used a debugger and am still at my wits end, people can remind me that I am just a low-level ComSci student. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good job on finding it. As for the sass, sorry if you feel slighted, but for every Sarah Awesome who has used the debugger, there's 100 non-awesome others who haven't. Good luck with your assignment. And a small sidenote: you may want to re-examine your 'lcrs::print' which is a little over-complicated and could be simplified and made easier to understand (and debug).